# Will (await method).ToList() block the thread?

Tags: c#, async, .net-core

I'm using a lot of `async Task<IEnumerable<T>>` methods and I want to stop doing this everytime to get the items as a list:

```cs
var items = await AsyncMethodThatReturnsEnumerable();
var enumeratedItems = items.ToList();
```

So, if I do something like this

```cs
var items = (await AsyncMethodThatReturnsEnumerable()).ToList()
```

Will it run asynchronously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Your code is equivalent to this:

```
var value = await AsyncMethodThatReturnsEnumerable(); // this is asynchronous
var list = value.ToList(); // this is _not_ asynchrounous
```

All you have done is written that on one line without the variable `value` in between.  As long as your `IEnumerable<T>` is reasonably sized, then you probably won't notice the delay of iterating everything into a `List<T>`.

The `await` keyword is like a bookmark, so when the asynchronous method is done, you are returned to the thread context you called the method from.  During the time the asynchronous method is running the calling thread is not blocked.

Comment: " As long as your IEnumerable<T> is reasonably sized, then you probably won't notice the delay of iterating everything into a List<T>" this is up to to the concrete implementation, it could be so that getting only one element or even stepping to the end might be quite noticeable.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't mix `async` and `yield return` which means the `IEnumerable<T>` is usually pre-populated when you get it.

Comment: That's right you cannot traverse IEnumerable asynchronously but it may initiate synchronous IO or some heavy computations.

Comment: @max630 the question asks "are these equivalent". They may be equivalently slow, at which point you can investigate changing to `Task<IEnumerable<Task<T>>>` or somesuch